# Analyzing social media group members: dropping incomplete data or interpolating missing values?

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, missing-data

I am analysing a set of group members on social media. I have 4 parameters that I plan to include into the analysis: age, sex, city and education level. The problem is that I can make up to ~25% of total group members with all 4 parameters in place, because most of the profiles do not contain all 4 pieces of information.

**The goal** is to get a general sense of demographics among this group: *sex composition*, *distribution by education level, city and age group*.
My data contains many missing values, and they occur in every one of these fields.

I am new to data analysis and struggle to **choose the right approach to solving the problem of missing data**.
I have thought of such options:

1. Insert values instead of missing data, using pandas' interpolation methods (particularly pad).
2. Drop all rows with NaN values and analyse the remains. (this will destroy 75% of all the rows in a table)
3. Ignore missing values and use different sample size for each of the metrics? Example: records like `{age: NaN, sex: female, education: NaN, city: NaN}` will be counted towards sex distribution but no other. On the contrary, record `{age: 24, sex: female, education: Secondary, city: London}` will be counted towards all four indices. Considering that, sex distribution may reflect almost 99% of actual subscribers, but age distribution will be analysed based on data from only 25% of total group members count.

So I hope to receive an advice on **what approach should I choose** in this particular situation.

I am using python library pandas for analysis, but I welcome any suggestions regarding overall directions :)

Comment: this question is a bit general (and also seems to be several questions in one), so it's possible people might vote to close it. i think you should consider narrowing the scope of your question – maybe start by asking how to interpolate categorical variables such as sex, city, and education level. also what kind of analysis are you trying to do? what do you want to determine from those four features? this would help provide some background

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I added some clarifications and examples as well as narrowed down the question itself.

Comment: Your goal seems to be to **impute** [missing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missing_data#Types) values, and then perform some analysis. But you didn't describe the protocol for collection nor the processes that cause subjects to report `NaN` for certain categorical values, and you didn't describe the analysis which will consume raw or imputed values. As stated, the OP does not admit of good answers.

Comment: It is stated that the value is considered NaN if no such value can be obtained (I use API. If the response does not contain necessary field, It is considered NaN). Is it even relevant? The analysis is finding distribution of a population by age/education/city groups and is stated as such. The scope of the question is to get a professional opinion of whether it is acceptable to a)lose that big chunk of data b)use different subsets of members for different metrics. Also I thank you for directing me towards imputing values, I will read on this (although, not exactly the answer to my question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the background you have provided us, I think it's important to emphasize that the data you have consists of categorical features, and as far as I can tell there isn't any order in how your data set is collected.

This rules out the possibility of using the pandas `.pad` method for filling missing values because this method forward fills or backfills missing values. To illustrate a common use case for the pad method, consider some random signal timeseries data where some signal value drops to 0 before becoming null.

```
                  time  signal_value
0  2023-01-01 00:00:00           5.0
1  2023-01-01 00:00:01           2.0
2  2023-01-01 00:00:02           1.0
3  2023-01-01 00:00:03           0.0
4  2023-01-01 00:00:04           0.0
5  2023-01-01 00:00:05           NaN
6  2023-01-01 00:00:06           NaN
7  2023-01-01 00:00:07           NaN
8  2023-01-01 00:00:08           NaN
9  2023-01-01 00:00:09           0.0
10 2023-01-01 00:00:10           0.0
```

In this case, it makes sense to forward or backfill the missing values.

But if you have a bunch of unordered data from social media accounts:

```
    age     sex education  city
0  24.0    male      None  None
1  25.0  female      None  None
2   NaN    None      None  None
3   NaN    None      None  None
4  22.0    None      None  None
5   NaN    male      None  None
6  33.0  female      None  None
```

I don't think it makes sense to use forward or backfill to replace missing values in the `age` or `sex` categories (not to mention `education` or `city`, which seem impossible to fill unless you have more information, such as a relatively rare case like a single-gender university).

Therefore, I think you need to choose between dropping all rows with any missing value, or analyzing the features separately. If you analyze the features separately, you will have people that count toward the analysis of one feature but not another so you should probably first determine if there is any pattern in the missing values. For example, if no one from `City A` has their age listed but this city is composed of predominantly older people with higher than average levels of education, you may be skewing your data if you analyze something like education level by age. Determining patterns in missing data is well summarized in [this article](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/10/a-complete-guide-to-dealing-with-missing-values-in-python/), which I encourage you to read.

That being said, you can perform an analysis based on dropping rows with missing data in any column versus the same analysis based on dropping rows with missing data in only one column and see if the analysis is similar – this could a be reasonable proxy to determine if your data is missing completely at random. If your data is completely missing at random, then with a large enough data set, you can assume the distribution of each feature should stay approximately the same, and you can analyze each feature separately.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The article was indeed very helpful! May I ask you to direct me to some helpful reading on how to determine if a dataset is "large enough"? I found something called "10 times rule", but I don't think that it is it.

Comment: the 10 times rule is a very general rule of thumb that says your data set should have 10 times the number of rows are there are features. as is often the case, the answer to your question about whether you have "enough data" is that it depends. to help you get started, i'd recommend performing some basic data analysis. how many non-null observations do you have for each feature? are there any major class imbalances (how many observations do you have for each unique category within a feature)?

Comment: Thank you! Now I have these 2 approaches in mind:
1) Find "all-four-together" sample size when the results differ from ones obtained from separate feature analysis by less then some requirement. 2) Calculate sample size using formulas, i. e. Cochran's. Then with 99% confidence, 1% margin of error and 50% standard of deviation I will get minimum sample size. And, assuming my data is missing completely at random, I will get the minimum for 'large enough' dataset (with no NaNs). Also I think I am getting carried away from the question, so please correct me and I will mark your post as accepted.

Comment: @JustUsNow both ideas sound reasonable – i don't know the amount of your data you have, but i imagine you've used cochran's formula to calculate you'll want `n = 16590` though this is really just a guide (i'd point out that cochran's is a statistical tool, but you might want to think about the data as well. for example, if you had no records in a particular category that you would expect to have. let's say you know there should be records of people with PhDs, but you didn't sample enough people  even though you're above cochran's threshold. then you need to increase the sample size further)

Comment: your current question (and this answer) focus mostly on ways of dealing with missing values from categorical features. at this point, we are now discussing how to calculate sample size for categorical data with missing values. i'm happy to discuss further, but you might consider asking about sample size as a separate question (this just helps keep stackoverflow organized). hopefully this has been helpful!

Comment: Yes, your answer and comments were a major boost to me! I found some good reading on both imputing values and correct sampling in the process. Now I have the general direction to follow in analysing categorical data with missing values. Choosing the sample size is indeed a separate topic and I will conduct my own research first :) Again, thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome and I'm glad my answer was helpful!